# What's the difference between `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and `maven-compiler-plugin`?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-3

I do not know the difference between `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and `maven-compiler-plugin`.

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Is that mean `Spring Boot Maven Plugin`'s feature include `maven-compiler-plugin`?

I just use `Spring Boot Maven Plugin` is ok, do not need add 2 plugins??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"[Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) provides Spring Boot support in Maven, letting you package executable jar or war archives and run an application “in-place”."

"[Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) is used to compile the sources of your project."

Comment: so I just use one `Spring Boot Maven Plugin` is ok?

Comment: @kkkkkk am looking answer for the same question , is it ok if use only one

Answer (score 7):

maven-compiler-plugin has two goals. Both are already bound to their proper phases within the Maven Lifecycle and are therefore, automatically executed during their respective phases.

compiler:compile is bound to the compile phase and is used to compile the main source files.
compiler:testCompile is bound to the test-compile phase and is used to compile the test source files.

To understand more about maven build lifecycle - http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference

maven-compiler-plugin usages -

- To compile source code using -source and -target javac Options
- To compile source code using a different JDK
- To compile source code using Memory Allocation Enhancement
- To Pass Compiler Arguments

Most commonly used to define source and target versions.
Sometimes you may want to compile a certain project to a different version than what you are currently using. The javac can accept such command using -source and -target. maven-compiler-plugin can also be configured to provide these options during compilation.

For example, if you want to use the Java 8 language features (-source 1.8) and also want the compiled classes to be compatible with JVM 1.8 (-target 1.8), you can either add the two following properties, which are the default property names for the plugin parameters:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  [...]
</project>
```

or configure the plugin directly:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Technically we can use both spring-boot-maven-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin in combination if the requirement is to create an executable jar as well as make sure source and target code have a specific version (which is accomplished by including maven-compiler-plugin).

In my case, i didn't use in combination but when my java project is a spring boot app that needs to run as a micro-service etc then we need an executable jar as build output so used spring boot maven plugin (only) but my other java project that consists of spring beans or components and is going to be used as a spring enabled library in other external apps but not required to run on its own but had to make sure source and target versions are specified then normal "mvn  package" generated jar should work. For that maven compiler plugin (only) should do the job.